Original meaning very very lost in translation. Cool stuff. (New to linguistics)
I am writing only to share something cool but I'd appreciate insights from you guys.
I wanted to translate Rammstein's song "Du hast" to Hebrew and look at the result. The main lyrics make absolutely no sense when translated and I find the gigantic linguistic difference too cool not to share.
Du = אתה (You)
Du hast = יש לך(Literally: There is to you).
Du hast mich יש לך אותי(Literally: There is to you 'et' me).
Du hast mich gefragt = שאלת אותי (You asked me).

את (et) is used as a Direct Object marker in Hebrew, if not included the sentence makes no sense.
** אותי = (את + אני): Et + me.
*** The 'ת' in שאלת indicates Past tense, second person (m. or f. depending on pronunciation).

TRANSLATION TO HEBREW:
אתה, יש לך, יש לך אותי, שאלת אותי.
Is it the morphological characteristics of Hebrew (suffixes in this case) and the sentence order that makes the translation lose the original meaning?

It’s the mismatch between the morphosyntactic properties of German and those of Hebrew that makes the translation not work; this is far from uncommon. In an example like the beginning of Du hast, where single words are ‘revealed’ individually at the end of a repeated sentence, a direct translation won’t work between most language pairs, even ones that are otherwise quite similar. English “You – You have – You have me – You asked me” isn’t much better than the Hebrew version. Greek would be even worse: “Εσύ – Έχεις – Μ’έχεις – Μ’ερώτησεις”.

(That should be με ρώτησες at the end there.)

Thank you for the comment!

What do you mean by translation? Sounds literal to me but I don't read Hebrew.

A simple explanation of Rammstein's lyrics from a native perspective should show that a literal translation is impossible.

The overt parse of the call and response schema escalating from "Du" to "Du hast mich gefragt" is adding one word per stanza until the line is completed. In this view, you'd have to begin with Du hast mich gefragt (You have asked me) and work your way backwards removing pieces bit by bit. This will result in nonsense.

The overt reading of the progression upto resolution must be "du hasst mich" (you hate me). HAVE does not obtain because pronomially indexed (?) persons are normally not possessed; we don't perceive relations of mutual affection this way, typically termed "love".
If somebody falls and you offer support you might say I got you but that's about it. Since haben (have) and hass (hate) are true homophones in parts of each paradigm because of sound change (compare Middle English you ha(ve)st), the rhyme cannot be translated into different paradigms without loss of felicity or fidelity ... except perhaps in a random coincidence that would not be structural and therefore not linguistically grounded.

The intended ambiguity (2) is cheesy because the second iteration (as well as the title "Du hast") is ungrammatical in any case: Haben and hassen are transitive under normal circumstances. Sure you could say "I just hate. Period" ("haters gonna hate"), but it's clearly done for effect (1) and not so meaningful.



Is it the morphological characteristics of Hebrew (suffixes in this case) and the sentence order that makes the translation lose the original meaning?

This is not about Hebrew in particular. You cannot say "* I have." (nor "there is to you" as you have suggested) out of context. Hence, no translation will be perfect.
